# Get the next id in the primary key order

Tags: sql, postgresql, loops, plpgsql

I want to loop over IDs for a given condition:

```
    BEGIN
    ...LOOP
     SELECT attr FROM emp INTO myAttr where id=givenID;
     IF <condition> THEN
        givenID = __successorID(givenID)__; -- dummy func. of getting next id in order
     END IF;
    END LOOP;
    END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Simply how can I get the next `id` according to `id` order in the `emp` table i.e. how to obtain the dummy `succesorID` function functionality?

Eg.:
in case of series of `id`:1,2,3,4 the `succesor(3)` would be 4 etc.

I need to get next `id` value in table for a given `id` using an imperative iterative construct.

**EDIT**
I want to find the min PK indexed value based on non-indexed column (here date `the_date`) value. The pk is increasing while the dates are also monothonic.

Is the following, full solution optimal then, or can it be optimised in some way?:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_min_find_by_date (
     the_date DATE
 ) RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
    mid_val INTEGER;
    max_id INTEGER;
    min_id INTEGER;
    mid_id INTEGER;
    act_date DATE;
BEGIN
    min_id=1;
    SELECT MAX (id) INTO max_id FROM invoices;
    WHILE min_id <= max_id LOOP
    mid_id = (min_id + max_id) >> 1;
    SELECT actual_date FROM invoices INTO act_date WHERE id=mid_id;
    IF act_date < the_date THEN
        min_id = mid_id +1
    ELSE IF act_date > the_date THEN
        max_id = mid_id -1  
    ELSE   
        RETURN mid_id
    END IF;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN -(min_id); -- date not found
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Create:

```
CREATE TABLE invoices (
   id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   issue_time timestamp NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO invoices (id, issue_time)
VALUES
   (1, '2017-05-09 00:01:01')
 , (2, '2017-05-09 00:01:01')
 , (3, '2017-05-09 00:01:01')
 , (4, '2017-05-09 00:01:01')

 , (5, '2017-05-09 00:02:02')
 , (6, '2017-05-09 00:02:02')
 , (7, '2017-05-09 00:02:02')

 , (8, '2017-05-09 00:02:03')

 , (9, '2017-05-09 00:03:03')
 , (10,'2017-05-09 00:03:03')
 , (11,'2017-05-09 00:03:03');
```

So assuming that the `timestamps` are non-decreasing I want to get min/max `id` for given `timestamp`. I use stored procedure here because I want to benchmark the time of its execution comparing to other implementation using the `clock_timestamp();` procedure.

**Is my procedure optimal way for getting the min/max using binary search or is there more optimal solution?**

Comment: This sounds strange. What is the **real** problem you are trying to solve here? Why do you use a loop and not a single query?

Comment: Just added clarification to post

Comment: I still have no idea what you are trying to achieve. Why do you need the "next ID"? What you are doing with that? Why are you iterating in a loop instead of using a query? Please **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). If you are trying to generate unique IDs by this then do **NOT** do it like that. Use a sequence

Comment: I want to find a minimal ID for a given non-key attr value. It is like a binary search in a sorted by id array. I dont want to generate I want to find. In normal icremantal manner I could put simply `id= id+1` but would it always make sens?

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: And it's always best to provide a minimal *complete* plpgsql function including the header. And your version of Postgres, obviously.

Comment: Your question is still incomplete. Postgres version? Obvious syntax errors (you never tried your code). Is `actual_date` monotonically increasing with the `id`? Explanation for what you are trying to achieve. You write about aspects of your perceived solution, nothing about the objective per se. There may be a far superior solution ...

Comment: This could be an x/y question, please clarify the problem you are trying to solve rather than explaining the solution you think you need

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Any solution for version `9.2.18+` would be sufficient. The issue is, that `date` monotonicity is increasing for some `id`s intervals while is decreasing in other `id` intervals. This is why for given `date` I want to find the min/max id interval and then rewrite given date-based query to simillar one based on the indexed `id` column instead on non-indexed `date` column within min-max inteval (order dependency).

Comment: I am almost certain the whole task can be resolved with a single (advanced) SQL statement. The description is just not clear (to me). If you provided a demo with table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement) with all data types and constraints, sample values and expected result, that should make it clear.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I have provided the requested info.

Comment: What's wrong with using `date between date+4sec and date+9sec`?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how I correctly understand your question.

If you have `givenID` and based on this, you need get next `id` in primary key column, then this is very simple:

```
select min(id) as next_id from table where id > givenID
```

Comment: Can't I just type `id=id+1`? Would it always make sens?

Comment: @mCs - If you're sure, that there is no "holes" in your id column, then you can. Though, almost always, there are (and if not currently, you should expect) those "holes" in primary key column.

Comment: So query is the only plpgsql solution of this problem that could handle the issiues with id "holes" that you are aware of?

Comment: @mCs - This is not plpgsql  at all, but simple sql, also there are many other ways, for finding next value in PK. IMHO, this is simplest way for this.